# How can I add conditions for copying

Tags: bash, copy

I am trying to copy SQL files.

The **filenames** are versions:

```
001.000.000.000001.sql
```

I do have to current **DB Version** in a **variable**. The string with the version looks like this:

```
2002000000020
```

I don't want to copy all of the files. I just want to copy the files with a version higher than the DB currently has.

I tried to do this with a for loop and an if-statement, but realized quickly that this is slow.

### My first approach looked like this:

```bash
for d in $archive_deltascripts_dir/*; do
  for f in $d/*; do
    local filename=$(basename "$f")
    cp -r "$f" "$path"
  done
done

for f in $release_deltascripts_dir/*; do
  local filename=$(basename "$f")
  cp -r "$f" "$path"
done
```

### Currently I'm just copying all files without loop:

```bash
for d in $archive_deltascripts_dir/*; do
  cp -r "$d/." "$path"
done
cp -r "$release_deltascripts_dir/." "$path"
```

Is there anyway to add conditions which files should be copied without having to use a for-loop?

I can convert the version in the filename to the same syntax the Database has:

```
echo ${scriptName} | sed 's/\(^[0-9]\{1\}\.[0-9]\{3\}\.[0-9]\{3\}\.[0-9]\{6\}\).*$/\1/g' | sed 's/\.//g'`
```

Comment: You can first create the list of files to copy (`sort -V` could help) and next copy them all at once (or with `xargs` if the list is very long). But to help you we would need to know what the _DB version_ looks like, where it comes from, etc. See, for instance, [How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try:

```bash
ls |awk -F '.' '($1 >= '$version1' && $2 >= '$version2' && $3 >= '$version3' && $4 >= '$version4')' |xargs -I {} cp {} /path/target
```

I am not sure what's the relation between `2002000000020` and `001.000.000.000001`.  Maybe you need

```bash
version=001000000000001
version1=`echo $version |cut -c-3`
version2=`echo $version |cut -c4-6`
version3=`echo $version |cut -c7-9`
version4=`echo $version |cut -c10-`
```

Comment: Could you explain what this command is doing?

Comment: 2002000000020 is how the version is saved in the database. 001.000.000.000001.sql is the  filename.

Comment: `ls` show all filename; `awk` filter files by version; `xargs` means do something for each input from input. in this case it copy each files by filtered filename to `/path/target`. `{}` is a placeholder, which will replaced by filename.

Comment: well, you can convert version string like `2002000000020` to filename's style.